# How do I fix the followin XmlEncode Function?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have the following function:

```
Private Function XMLEncode(ByVal s As String) As String
        Return s.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("'", "&apos;").Replace("""", "&quot;").Replace("AMP",amp)
    End Function
```

but the above takes the string `"TYNE &AMP; WEAR"` and produces:

`TYNE &amp;amp; WEAR`

I just want it to be `TYNE &amp; WEAR`

The xml is built with StringBuilder and that is what I am stuck with right now. I know .net takes care of this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
Private Function XMLEncode(ByVal s As String) As String
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "(?i)&amp;", "&")   ' unescape escaped ones
        Return s.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("'", "&apos;").Replace("""", "&quot;")
    End Function
```

Instead of having this function yourself (and reinventing the wheel), you can use [SecurityElement.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape%28VS.80%29.aspx#Y499):

```
text = SecurityElement.Escape(s)
```

or [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) (if you're in ASP.Net)

```
text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s)
```

Also, instead of `StringBuilder`, if you can switch to [`XmlTextWriter`](http://XmlTextWriter.WriteString), then `XmlTextWriter.WriteString()` will do the escaping for you.

Comment: If I remove it, I end up with TYNE &amp;AMP; WEAR
If I put it before, I end up with TYNE &amp;amp; WEAR

Comment: I know, it was originally with StringBuilder, but I can't do anything about that now

Comment: So then the last replace should be `.Replace("&amp;amp;", "&amp;")`

Comment: That would work if it was "&amp;&amp;", but what if it is in a different case or in some other format.

Comment: Then use `Regex.Replace` before returning the string: `return Regex.Replace(s, "(?i)&amp;amp;", "&amp;")`. `(?i)` makes it case insensitive. Also, check my update for another way.

Comment: Is there performance difference between using the regex in agent-j's answer as opposed to yours?

Comment: It uses [Negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which is bit expensive. But it is slightly better as it handles those other cases as well. IF you don't want to get into regex mess, use `return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s))`. This will first unescape all those characters and then escape them properly. You just need to add a reference to `System.Web` assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to double-escape the xml markup, consider using a regular expression replacement that won't double-escape the xml.

```
' encode "&", but not "&amp;", "&gt;", "&lt;", or "&quot;".'
s = Regex.Replace (s, "&(?!(?:amp|lt|gt|quot);)", "&amp;", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
' encode other xml characters.'
Return s.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("'", "&apos;").Replace("""", "&quot;").Replace("AMP",amp)
```